# Can I store variables in WSF file for use in the script part?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

As an alternative to this...

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
sqlquery = "    some text just for demonstrating what I mean " & _
           "    some text just for demonstrating what I mean " & _
           "    some text just for demonstrating what I mean "

statement = connection.execute(sqlquery)

'more code

</script>
</job>
```

Is something like this possible? ...

```
<job>

<sqlquery>
some text just for demonstrating what I mean
some text just for demonstrating what I mean
some text just for demonstrating what I mean
</sqlquery>

<script language="VBScript">

statement = connection.execute(sqlquery)

' more code


</script>
</job>
```

In other words,  is it possible to store a variable (in this case a large multi line string) within the XML part of a WSF file and then use that variable within the script?

I am trying to avoid having to store large multi line strings in this ugly way within vbscript code.

I know I can store the string in a separate file and read it in (and I do do that) but I am asking this question to establish whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

By chance I had to read the ActivePerl User Guide topic "Windows Script Host" and found `<resource>/getResource`. On microsoft.com I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/39s1fhfy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). I modified the sample to show the importance of CDATA:

```
<package>
<job id="VBS">
<resource id="errNonNumeric">
<![CDATA[
  Error: A non-numeric value was entered where a number was expected.
         And value <> nice!
         So we need CDATA
]]>
</resource>
<script language="VBScript">

Function getRandomNumber(upperBound)
   If IsNumeric(upperBound) Then
      getRandomNumber = CInt(upperBound * Rnd + 1)
   Else
      WScript.Echo qq(getResource("errNonNumeric"))
      WScript.Quit -1
   End If
End Function

Function qq(s):qq=""""&s&"""":End Function

NewValue = getRandomNumber("Bad Value")

</script>
</job>
</package>
```

output:

```
cscript 37990815-4.wsf
"

  Error: A non-numeric value was entered where a number was expected.
         And value <> nice!
         So we need CDATA

"
```

Some work wrt whitespace still seems necessary.

---

**Old version; kept to show that rtfm beats 'roll your own'.**

If you are willing to

1. write your XML 'by the book'
2. add a function using the MSXML2.DomDocument to each .WSF
3. do some extra work wrt whitespace

you can.

Demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<package>
 <job id="main">
  <?job error="true" debug="false" ?>
  <script language="VBScript">
   <![CDATA[
' ############################################################################

Function getXmlData(n)
  Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXDoc.async = False
  oXDoc.load WScript.ScriptFullName
  getXmlData = "shit hits fan"
  If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
     Dim ndX : Set ndX = oXDoc.selectSingleNode("/package/job[@id='main']/data/" & n)
     getXmlData = ndX.text
  End If
End Function
Function qq(s):qq=""""&s&"""":End Function

WScript.Echo qq(getXmlData("s"))


' ############################################################################
   ]]>
  </script>
  <data>
   <s>
    pi
    pa
    po
   </s>
  </data>
 </job>
 <job id="other">
  <data><s>wtf</s></data>
 </job>
</package>
```

output:

```
cscript 37990815-2.wsf
"pi
    pa
    po"
```